# How to display line number before \Require in algorithmic environment

Tags: algorithms, line-numbering, algorithmic, algpseudocode

Here is my code snippet:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithm, algpseudocode}
\begin{document}
    \begin{algorithm}
        \caption{Test}
        \begin{algorithmic}[1]
            \Require Something
            \Repeat
            \State Whatever
            \Until{Forever}
        \end{algorithmic}
    \end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I want the line numbering also appear in the first line, before the Require statement. How can I do that? I think that this looks more inline/better, however, could I be violating a programming guideline?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is to write the Require line manually as a statement:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithm, algpseudocode}
\begin{document}
    \begin{algorithm}
        \caption{Test}
        \begin{algorithmic}[1]
            \State \textbf{Require:} Something
            \Repeat
            \State Whatever
            \Until{Forever}
        \end{algorithmic}
    \end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Regarding programming guidelines: there are no fixed rules on how to format pseudocode or which lines are numbered. Therefore you can follow your personal preference. However, from a programming point of view, the requirements for an algorithm are not really part of (the execution of) the algorithm, which is an argument *not* to number them (and probably the reason why they are not numbered by default in `algpseudocode`).